# Retrieving chars from a linked list

Tags: c++, string, linked-list, char

C++ question here. I've successfully (after some research :P) created a linked-list implementation for a stack of ints. I'm having some trouble modifying it for char*'s though...

I think it may just be an issue with referenceing/dereferencing pointers in relation to the functions used by the linklistCommands class I have defined below. (I've always had trouble understanding when to use & or * in relation to arguments and return values.) I've commented the lines in my code that I probably muddled up.

Anyways, here is my code thus far:

```
struct linkc { // one 'link', stores a pointer to a char array
  char * value;
  linkc *next;
};

class linklistCommands 
{
  public:
    linklistCommands()
      {top = NULL;}
    ~linklistCommands() 
      {}
    void push(char * address) // Pretty sure I'm OK here.
      {
      linkc *temp = new linkc;
      temp->value = address;
      temp->next = top;
      top = temp;
      } 
    char* pop() // Pretty sure I have to change something on this line
      {
      if (top == NULL) 
        return 0;
      linkc * temp;
      temp = top;
      char * value;
      value = temp->value;
      top = temp->next;
      delete temp;
      return value;
      }
    bool isEmpty()
      {
      if (top == NULL) 
        return 1;
      return 0;
      }
  private:
    linkc *top; 
};

int main(void)
{

 // pushed strings are of an arbitrary, but always known, length
 char[4] stringA = "foo"; 
 char[6] stringB = "fooba"; 
 char[8] stringC = "foobar "; 

 linklistCommands commandList;

 commandList.push(stringA);    
 commandList.push(stringB);
 commandList.push(stringC);

 while(commandList.isEmpty!=1)
 {
  cout << (*commandList.pop()) << endl;
 }
}
```

Thanks for reading through my question and/or any clarification you can provide :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your class seems ok, but the main needs to be changed:

```
 // pushed strings are of an arbitrary, but always known, length
 char stringA[] = "foo";
 char stringB[] = "fooba";
 char stringC[] = "foobar ";

 linklistCommands commandList;

 commandList.push(stringA);
 commandList.push(stringB);
 commandList.push(stringC);

 while(commandList.isEmpty()!=1)
 {
  cout << commandList.pop() << endl;
 }
```

You should consider to use std::string instead of char*, it's easier and safer.
Also, char[N] stringA = "..."; it's C# or Java syntax, not C++

Comment: Note that if your stringA, stringB, etc. go out of scope (which they won't in the main, but they might if declared in another function), they will cease to exist everywhere (well they may or may not, depending on basically unrelated other things your program is doing), and your stack will return garbage if they're later popped off.  Using std::string will prevent this.

Comment: Ah. StringA,stringB aren't part of my actual code, but are rather just there to placehold. As for my actual variables, I'm managing the memory for those such that they're never used out of scope.

Comment: chac, can I/should I not be using char[N] in C++? I typed char[N] there just to indicate that the strings could be of varying lengths but that the length would be known, but my actual code doesn't have the strings initialized to their final values - they rather get added a character at a time, from a loop.

Comment: char X[N] it's legacy C syntax. It's perfectly fine when used appropriately, and possibly more lightweight than std::string. But requires idiomatic constructs and much more attention. For instance, x + 3 **doesn't** concatenate, but offsets the pointer...

Answer (score 0):

you have to allocate and manage the char* data field and copy the input value. :) (or use strdup() at the least). you might also want to look at const char* as the type of the input data

Answer (score 0):

I am sending from my cell, so short answer: & is for getting the address of the current element and * is for getting the value from an address. So by using * twice, you can get the the value from an address pointing to an address of a value.

Comment: Yeah, I usually get that well enough but I feel like the meanings change when the operators are being used to define function return values or in function arguments.

Comment: Not really, but I guess you will need to look how it compiles to understand why it is this way. Anyway, one star means, that you return with an address of a value and two starts mean, that you have an address of an address of a value. What the compiler needs to know is what memory layout your value has (type) and how often it has to follow addresses.